# SSE 4 memory load optimizations

Tags: intel, sse

When using SSE instructions/intrinsics, say for 256-bit registers, has anyone been able to reduce time spent loading the extended registers from memory by using either the prefetch instruction on the next 32-byte chunk, or by some other technique? Assume the data to be loaded is already properly aligned in memory.

Comment: x86 is already capable of doing this - if you are fetching a particular set of totally ordered items (in logical memory) then this data will probably find itself on the L2 cache prior to the `mov`

Comment: Is the "4" in your title shorthand for the word "for"?  You don't seem to be talking about SSE4's [MOVNTDQA](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVNTDQA.html) load instruction, or anything else to do with SSE4 specifically.  (256b vectors are an AVX feature).

Comment: I was somewhat vague on purpose because we are still discussing the commercial implications of requiring specific instruction sets. So, my question was more along the lines of asking about general guidelines for reducing memory latencies with wide registers. I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more info about x86 CPU performance.  Hardware prefetchers are pretty good at locking onto patterns of sequential access, so you don't usually need software prefetch instructions.

Usually it's not a win to do a wide vector load an unpack it into separate integer registers.  Once you've touched a cache line, more loads from it are cheap, and throughput from L1 cache into registers isn't usually the problem.  Using ALU instruction to unpack a 256b load into separate 32 or 64b integers just takes more instructions and means you're more likely to bottleneck on ALU throughput.